# Slow first query after update to spelling dictionary

Tags: marklogic

We are using spell:suggest and the spell:suggest-detailed api’s for fetching the correct words from a custom spell dictionary. Now if we update the spell dictionary and then fire the query, it takes a long time to return the results for the first hit. Again if we fire the same query the time taken to return back the results is considerably reduced. 
Is it related to re-indexing of the spell dictionary every time it is updated or has some other reasons behind it. Can you please suggest some ways which  will help to improve the performance of the first hit.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance !!

Comment: Do you have any online reference for spawn calls in Asynchronous mode. Something like below or any form of spawn call in Marklogic. My Asynchronous call(Transaction 1: Insert Dictionary Entry, 2: Spawn calls to search with dummy or actual search term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to spawn a task that calls the `spell:suggest` functions in order to get the caches rebuilt, before an end user tries using them. You can do this directly after each update.

On the other hand, if updates are likely to occur not very often, then why bother? Not sure why you need to update the custom dictionary regularly, but I'd expect not many changes after perhaps a short burst in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea. let me try to implement this logic and let you know how i am improving. Thanks again for great help.

Comment: I have implemented your solution, but still i am facing the performance issue. Its look like sometime its working fine, but most of the time, we are facing the same performance issue. Any further help appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: @Selvakumar Could you test the performance using the Profile feature of CQ or QueryConsole? That should tell what takes most time. The performance hit might just come from the number of suggestions being returned. Do you limit that?

Comment: Hi, Now the query search result comes fast but updating the dictionary takes 7 seconds. The performance delay shifted form Query Search Result to Updating the dictionary. Though it is an spawn call, we can make that call after insert/update/delete happens in the dictionary then only the result will contain the inserted/updated values.Can you help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @Selvakumar Can you elaborate? You could perhaps update the question with more/newer details, or switch to ML mailing list briefly, and update here later.

Comment: Hi Greet,
My basic question is Slow first query after update to spelling dictionary. After your suggestion, i have implemented "spawn a task that calls the spell:suggest" in my program, now my search query is working better. But now the insert call to dictionary takes time. I have two functionality, 1. Insert a entry to dictionary 2. Fetch the corresponding entry or some other entry from dictionary. By applying your suggestion functionality 2 is working fine. But previously functionality 1 was taking less time, now it(functionality 1) takes more time. how to fix this?

Comment: My ultimate question is how efficiently or in which part of program i need to do the spawn call..Consider i may have continuous insert and continuous fetch from the same dictionary. how efficiently we can use the spawn call or any other fix to get good performance of insert and fetch calls.

Comment: @Selvakumar Perhaps easiest if you'd share the essential parts of your code. The spawn should be executed asynchronously, so it shouldn't result in a slower insert. But is easier to give detailed help with actual code.

Comment: Hi Greet, Do you have any online reference for spawn calls in Asynchronous mode.
Something like below or any form of spawn call in Marklogic.
My Asynchronous call(Transaction 1: Insert Dictionary Entry, 2: Spawn calls to search with dummy or actual search term)

Comment: @Selvakumar There are good examples in the documentation of MarkLogic itself. But it basically comes down to just calling an external xqy with xdmp:spawn('/path/to/my.xqy'). Reference can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#search.xqy?start=1&cat=all&query=xdmp:spawn&button=search As you can read, spawned tasks are always executed asynchronously. You would have to use xdmp:invoke or xdmp:eval to do things synchronously (e.g. wait for the results)..

Comment: thanks a lot Greet. You answered my issue. Awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Greet,
I have three separate file for db insert/update/delete and I have separate file for search spell/spell.xqy

At the end of three separate files(insert/update/delete), I am calling the below spawn function for search like below

declare variable $cat as xs:string external;
declare variable $spellFlag as xs:string external;

let $Spell := if (($cat eq "A" or $cat eq "B" or $cat eq "C") and $spellFlag eq "True") then
                                (xdmp:spawn("/spell/spell.xqy",

Comment: <dictionaries>A1_DICTIONARY,A2_DICTIONARY,A3_DICTIONARY,A4_DICTIONARY,B1_DICTIONARY,B2_DICTIONARY,B3_DICTIONARY,B4_DICTIONARY,
B5_DICTIONARY, B6_DICTIONARY,C1_DICTIONARY,C2_DICTIONARY,C3_DICTIONARY,C4_DICTIONARY</dictionaries><spelldictionaries>A1_Spell,A2_Spell,A3_Spell,A4_Spell, B1_Spell,B2_Spell,B3_Spell,B4_Spell,B5_Spell,B6_Spell, C1_Spell,C2_Spell,C3_Spell,C4_Spell</spelldictionaries><search>welcome</search></field></SearchFields>"))
)else() return()
spawn was working fine last week,now its taking more time as usual.if i add more dictionary in spawn call,it takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the dictionary will invalidate any caches associated with it. That is probably the immediate cause of the problem, but knowing that does not suggest a solution to me.

Why are you updating the spelling dictionary?

Have you considered using multiple dictionaries?

Comment: That is my requirement(update the dictionary in frequent interval). Is there any way in marklogic to do Asynchronous call(Transaction 1: Insert Dictionary Entry, 2: Spawn calls to search with dummy or actual search term)

Comment: Do you have any online reference for spawn calls in Asynchronous mode. Something like below or any form of spawn call in Marklogic. My Asynchronous call(Transaction 1: Insert Dictionary Entry, 2: Spawn calls to search with dummy or actual search term)